# How to "optimize" a object-creation IF

Tags: java

I have these workflow somethimes.

```
MyObj mo = null;
if (x == 1)
{
  mo = foo ();
}
else if (x == 2)
{
  ...
}
else
{
  mo = bar ();
}
```

I think it is not very "pretty" and there is a logical possibility (with more ifs and maybe no else) that the object would be undefined. I must handle that.

Is there a way I can make this more elegant? I think its pretty long for such a simple code.

I am not sure a case-statement or a ternary-if makes it better...

Comment: You can also try using switch-case construct. In general, you can throw a Runtime Exception if there are no match for any of the conditions (that is the final else). The runtime exception can be custom exception extending RuntimeException.

Comment: When I learned programming with C (20 years ago) it was bad style to have a switch/case. Is that different today or is that JDK14 construct different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if you want to be sure that all condition branches assign a value, you can only *declare* a variable on the first line. This way, the compiler will verify if the variable has been assigned before use. You can optionally make the variable *final* if you want to ensure it is assigned exactly once, to be sure it is assigned only in an if/else if/else block.

```java
final String myVar;
if (x == 0) myVar = "zero";
else if (x > 0) myVar = "positive";
else myVar = "negative";
```

Also, since java 14, you can use [switch expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/switch-expressions.html#GUID-BA4F63E3-4823-43C6-A5F3-BAA4A2EF3ADC) instead. It is a special type of switch that returns a variable, assigned by one of its branch (branches are exclusive).

A few notes about switch expressions:

- you cannot use complex conditions with it, only simple value comparison.
- If the tested variable is an enum value, you can make it exhaustive even without `default` branch, because the compiler is then able to check that all possible values have been tested in the switch.

Example:

```java
final String myVar = switch (x) {
    case 0 -> "zero"
    case 1 -> "one"
    default -> "other"
};
```

Comment: There is no requirement to make the variable final: definite assignment works for non-final local variables too. The important thing is not assigning an initial value of null to the variable

Comment: @AndyTurner You"re right, I will amend my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Map` behind the scenes and an appropriate abstraction to create an instance of `MyObj`. `Supplier<MyObj>` matches the example, but depending on the exact use case you may need `Function<Something, MyObj>` or even something custom.

```
public class MyObjFactory {

  private final Map<Integer, Supplier<MyObj>> factories = new HashMap<>();
  private final Supplier<MyObj> defaultFactory = () -> bar();

  public void registerFactory(Integer key, Supplier<MyObj> factory) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(key, "Null key not allowed");
    Objects.requireNonNull(factory, "Null factory not allowed");
    //no nulls allowed, ever!
    factories.put(key, factory);
  }

  public MyObj create(Integer key) {
    Supplier<MyObj> factory = factories.getOrDefault(key, defaultFactory);
    //if key has not been registered the default factory will instantiate MyObj
    return factory.get();
  }
}
```

The `defaultFactory` will make sure that you always receive an instance of `MyObj` regardless of input.

Register the factories:

```
MyObjFactory myObjFactory = new MyObjFactory();
myObjFactory.registerFactory(1, () -> foo());
//register other required factories
```

And use `MyObjFactory` to create instances:

```
//get myObjFactory, probably dependency injection
int x = //get x from wherever
MyObj myObj = myObjFactory.create(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

What Java version are you using ? If you use JDK 14+ you can use ["switch expressions"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/switch-expressions.html)

```java
var x = 1;
Object mo = switch (x) {
    case 1 -> new Object();
    default -> new Object();
};
System.out.println(mo);
```

> the object would be undefined. I must handle that.

With this syntax, the `default` case is required if the compiler detects that all cases are not handled. Otherwise you will get the error `The switch expression does not cover all possible input values`.

If you handled all possible values, the `default` is not required.

```
enum Type {
  FOO,
  BAR
}

var t = Type.FOO;
Object mo = switch (t) {
    case FOO -> "f";
    case BAR -> "b";
};
```

If one day you add a value in the enum, you will need to modify your code to handle this, which is nice.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite interesting and accurate answers. Using switch seems to be the most beautiful approach as long as it uses the new java 14+ syntax.

One recommendation with that one is to keep switches small. There's no any rule of thumb to say it should only have 3 or 5 cases, but keep them small enough for you and your team understand them, as well as to follow domain/business logic.

This is a good article to read https://www.baeldung.com/java-switch#switch-expressions

One important thing is, as I mentioned before, having in mind Domain/Business Logic.

If you see switch is growing and is getting larger, one question could be if that could be split into different switch statements, creating different helper methods or creating abstraction. Whatever fits better. There are different refactoring techniques as stated here

- https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism
- https://refactoring.guru/extract-method

After all this, if you are still not sure about which approach to follow, there's another option, that may increase the space complexity (memory usage) but will look quite nice to me. See below pseudocode example:

```
var map = {
    "obj1": function() { new Obj1() },
    "obj2": function() { new Obj2() },
    "obj3": function() { new Obj3() }
}

/* For you to create the object you only need to pass the id to the map. 
   That will get you the function that belongs that id and you just need 
   to execute it. That's why you need the last two parenthesis */
map.get("obj1")()
```

With this approach you can also make the values of your map, rather than a function the Object itself using an abstraction as return type.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using [pub/sub model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern), it might seems overkill for creating object here. But it did remove `if else`, and it decouples code.

Pseudo code

```
subscription1 = new Subscription();
subscription1.setTopic("projects/xis1");
subscription1.addListener((x)-> {
    // do a lot with x equals 1
})


subscription2 = new Subscription();
subscription2.setTopic("projects/xis2");
subscription2.addListener((x)-> {
    // do a lot with x equals 2
})

subscriptionWildCard = new Subscription();
subscriptionWildCard.setTopic("projects/xis*");
subscriptionWildCard.addListener((x)-> {
    // x could be anything else
})


MQClient.sendMessage("projects/xis" + x)
```